# AngularJS - Access a View element by Id from its associated Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jstree

In a controller I wish to access a element in my view so I can manipulate it when the user invokes an action. I'm currently using JQuery and JSTree and my current solution is:

```
$('#jstree_demo_div').jstree(true).hide_node(item);
```

and this works!

My issue occurs when I create a second instance of the same view and controller. Because I am selecting the views element using `$('#jstree_demo_div')`, when the above is invoked in either controller instance it always selects the first instance of jstree_demo_div in the DOM so only one view is working correctly.

**How do I limit my controller to only get elements within the scope of its associated view?**

My view is like this:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="listingsController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-4">
            <label style="position:fixed">Customers</label>
            <div style="overflow: auto; height:300px; margin-top:20px" id="jstree_demo_div" role="tree" aria-multiselectable="true"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have problem with jQuery.

Comment: Hi there, could you please elaborate the part : "when I create a second instance of the same view and controller.".

Comment: Well... Id's are unique, so you shouldn't be finding more than one, ever.

Comment: @ajaysinghdav10d I am trying to show the same data twice. So in two parts of the screen I have the same tree with the same data, but both are distinct instances.

Comment: @Goliadkin I get ids are unique, but then how do I interact with multiple instances of the same view?

Comment: @Cognition, If you know how many instances you need, I would advice using ng-repeat. Could you please tell us the factor that drives the count of instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular way would be to create a directive that contains your jstree then place multiple copies on your view. In your directive's link function you have access to the jQuery object that represents only children of that directive. There is where you would use a selector to do some work. See the section "Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM" at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

Comment: You were right, I just had to make my own directive. Thanks!